# 18.04 Screen zoomed- cannot navigate

Tags: screen, display-resolution, zooming

I upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04 but did not see any change to the desktop layout. I installed Gnome and the screen went to max zoom. I can no longer navigate or open a terminal or anything. I tried recovery mode but cannot get it to normalize.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 already has Gnome installed. How did you install Gnome on top that? Please edit your question with all the commands you used or details about which icons and apps you used to install which version of Gnome.

Comment: Sorry- I don't remember. I just googled for help and followed instructions to install Gnome, figuring that it would prompt me if it was already in there. I copied command line text and ran the commands.  I can't figure out how to get to a terminal due to the zoom issue. Gnome 3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recover files without a screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1128048/recover-files-without-a-screen)