# Recover files without a screen?

Tags: reinstall, zooming

My screen is zoomed to max rendering it useless to navigate. I need the files on the drive and I wanted to re-install Ubuntu 18.04 to fix the zoom problem since nothing else has worked to correct the problem but it wants to erase all files to do that. How can I recover my files?

Comment: Re-install using 'something-else', choose your partitions & do not have the 'format' check-box ticked.  It erases system directories only, installs Ubuntu then re-installs your added programs.  No data files are touched.  It's only one option, but if re-installing it'd be my choice; after backup first of course.

Comment: Do you know how you set you screen magnification?

Comment: " I wanted to re-install Ubuntu 18.04 to fix the zoom problem"  pretty drastic for such a simple problem. Besides the answer: booting from a live session also resets zoom for that instance.

Comment: I will try to re-install from my USB drive again but I did not see any options last time I looked that would preserve my files. I do not know how the screen magnification got the way it is. It happened after I tried to install Gnome, since the upgrade left the same desktop as I had with 16.04. Sigh... ignorance is NOT bliss.

Comment: So I reinstalled using 'something else' and made sure the format box was not checked. Installation worked perfectly except that I do not see any of my files. Is there a chance they are still available?

Answer (score 0):

Under the ***assumption*** that you have accidently enabled the 'Universal Access' zoom of the Gnome screen, you can reset this with a keyboard shortcut *even though* you can't see what you are doing:

Login to you computer

- Press <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> to toggle Zoom off or on
- Press <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> to Zoom in
- Press <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>-</kbd> to Zoom out

The souce I found for this information was by examining  settings->Devices->Keyboard->Universal Access shortcuts, and testing this on my computer.

---

This can also be done from a command line, if you can see the active part of the terminal window, with the commands

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.a11y.magnifier mag-factor 1.0`

to set the magnification to 1, or

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.a11y.applications screen-magnifier-enabled false`

to disable the magnification

Comment: The screen is zoomed so far that the pointer is more than half the height of the screen. Toggling zoom on and off on another machine does not give nearly the amount of zoom the ailing laptop is experiencing.

Comment: @DougThomas The zoom is variable:  When it is on, you can zoom further with super+alt+= and I can zoom to the point that my screen is full of cursor.  If this didn't help you ailing machine, then you have enabled a zoom other than the gnome desktop zoom.